# Can't have a view with multiple formpanels (SENCHA TOUCH 2)

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to make a view with multiple formpanels (5) each with a fieldset inside however from what I've read, a view can only contain 1 formpanel, when i set 5 only the first one is shown.

Initially I was using a view with multiple fieldsets and got the look I wanted, however, this solution doesn't allow me to set store records to these fieldsets so i could manage multiple records in the same view so I had to try making these fieldsets have a parent formpanel and thus my problem started.

MyConfigView.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyConfigView',{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.configview',
config:{
        layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation:{
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'left',
                duration: 8000
            }
        },
        items:[
        {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                ui: 'light',
                title: 'Yadayada', 
                itemId: 'toolbarMyConfigView',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'back',
                    text: 'Voltar',
                    action: 'voltarConfigView',
                    itemId: 'toolbarMyConfigViewVoltarBt'
                }

                ]

        },
                    {
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    items:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        title: 'Yada',
                        id: 'fieldSetAssalto',
                        model: 'Socorro.model.MyModel',
                        cls: 'x-floating',
                        items:[
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'numeroTelefone',
                                label: 'Yada'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'mensagem',
                                label: 'Yada'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                },

                {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items:[

                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        title: 'YADA',
                        itemId: 'fieldSetIncendio',
                        model: 'Socorro.model.MyModel',
                        cls: 'x-floating',

                        items:[
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'numeroTelefone',
                                label: 'yadada'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'mensagem',
                                label: 'yaaada'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items:[ 
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        title: 'YADADA',
                        itemId: 'fieldSetSequestro',
                        model: 'Socorro.model.MyModel',
                        cls: 'x-floating',

                        items:[
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'numeroTelefone',
                                label: 'Yadaaa'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'mensagem',
                                label: 'yadada'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        title: 'YADA',
                        itemId: 'fieldSetEmedico',
                        model: 'Socorro.model.MyModel',
                        cls: 'x-floating',

                        items:[
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'numeroTelefone',
                                label: 'YADAA'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name: 'mensagem',
                                label: 'Yada'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items:[
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            title: 'Yada',
                            itemId: 'fieldSetAcidente',
                            model: 'Socorro.model.MyModel',
                            cls: 'x-floating',

                            items:[
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    name: 'numeroTelefone',
                                    label: 'Yada'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    name: 'mensagem',
                                    label: 'Yada'
                                }
                            ]
                        }


                    ]
                }



]
}

});
```

Any ideas on how can i get a view with multiple formpanels to work using Sencha Touch 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your MyApp.view.MyConfigView view has a "card" layout applied, and this kind of layout allow you to display only a single sub view as active.
To display them all in the same view, I suggest you to set your view configuration as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyConfigView',{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.configview',
    config:{
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        }
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [
            ...
        ]
    }
});
```

In this way you will dispose the formpanels vertically in your view, giving them the same height.
PS: Remove the 'x-floating' class from them.

However, if you want to use a Card layout (which seems to be the best solution), I suggest you to give all your formpanels a different "itemId" config param.

```
xtype: 'formpanel',
itemId: 'assalto',
items: [
    ...
]
```

and then, using the ST MVC architecture, get these forms one by one, and calling the function.

```
.setRecord(<YOUR_RECORD>);
```

Read more on ST Controllers on Sencha's docs.
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/controllers

Comment: Some of those configs where leftovers of my attempts to get this to work, sorry ! I understand the solution of using container instead of a card but i didn't get the second part of your answer, regarding the possibility of going with the card layout since if I use this, it won't display the other formpanels..

Comment: Don't worry. In order to display other container cards (in your case other formpanels), you need to call the setActive method on your MyApp.view.MyConfigView to make them active, so visible on the screen.  You can get more info at the following url: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card